I can't change timezone using Date/MomentJS/MomentJS-TimeZone
import moment from "moment";
import momentTZ from "moment-timezone";

moment.locale("fr");
momentTZ.tz.setDefault("Europe/Paris");

console.log(moment(), moment().toDate());
console.log(moment(), momentTZ().toDate());
console.log(new Date().toString(), new Date().toISOString());


OUTPUT

Moment<2024-05-09T22:46:53+02:00> 2024-05-09T20:46:53.923Z
Moment<2024-05-09T22:46:53+02:00> 2024-05-09T20:46:53.925Z
Thu May 09 2024 22:46:53 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale) 2024-05-09T20:46:53.925Z

In three case, when i want the ISO Format, the method reset timezone
Switch process.env.TZ to Europe/Paris, reconfigure tzdata in the host
